# I want some null result with the help of this Query

Tags: mysql, case

Query

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN `tomato_rating` = 0 THEN 'NULL'
  WHEN `tomato_rating` != 0 THEN `tomato_rating`
  END `tomato_rating`,
  ur.`user_rating`, 
  ABS(tomato_rating - ur.`user_rating`) AS avg_guess_error  
FROM user_rating ur
  LEFT JOIN videos v
    ON ur.vid_id = v.id
WHERE ur.user_id = '1'
```

See the result screenshot for verification

[image]

Result Required

```
NULL - 50 NULL
50   - 30 20
65   - 33 32
NULL - 16 NULL
```

Comment: Forgive me but whats your question? You have an SQL statement and output.. do you have errors?

Comment: Why is your last column supposed to be null?  Because `user_rating` doesn't match `tomato_rating`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  IF (`tomato_rating` = 0, 'NULL', `tomato_rating`) as `tomato_rating`,
  ur.`user_rating`,
  IF (`tomato_rating` = 0, 'NULL', ABS(tomato_rating - ur.`user_rating`))
    as avg_guess_error  
FROM user_rating ur
LEFT JOIN videos v ON ur.vid_id = v.id
WHERE ur.user_id = '1'
```

Notice that you're using string `'NULL'` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me (Awesome) @Mosty Mostacho

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to return `NULL` if `tomato_rating = 0`.

To do this, you can use the [`NULLIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) function:

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(`tomato_rating`, 0) AS `tomato_rating`,
  ur.`user_rating`, 
  ABS(NULLIF(`tomato_rating`, 0) - ur.`user_rating`) AS avg_guess_error  
FROM user_rating ur
  LEFT JOIN videos v
    ON ur.vid_id = v.id
WHERE ur.user_id = '1'
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't know about `NULLIF` and `IFNULL`.

Comment: @telereader  Notice there are no null values in the original query. It is the String `'NULL'` what is being returned

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me (Awesome @Michael Ferdrickson i salute your experience )

Comment: @MostyMostacho True, but I don't think that was the OP's intent.  It wouldn't make sense to subtract a number from the string `'NULL'` and get `'NULL'`... that's the behavior of an actual `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN `tomato_rating` = 0 THEN 'NULL'
WHEN `tomato_rating` != 0 THEN `tomato_rating`
END `tomato_rating`,
ur.`user_rating`, 
CASE
WHEN `tomato_rating` = 0 THEN 'NULL'
WHEN `tomato_rating` != 0 THEN ABS(tomato_rating - ur.`user_rating`) 
END `avg_guess_error`,  
FROM user_rating ur
LEFT JOIN videos v
ON ur.vid_id = v.id
WHERE ur.user_id = '1'
```